# Configure Nginx for work in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I try connected nginx and symfony 2. But my configure file not work for this framework.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name test.com www.test.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|docx|xlsx)$ {
    root /home/test/var/www/test.com/public_html/web;
    index index.html index.php;
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
}



location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60;
    proxy_send_timeout 90;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Connection close;
    proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
    proxy_pass_header Content-Disposition;
    proxy_pass_header Content-Length;
}
```

}

For any static file which contain in directory
**/home/test/var/www/test.com/public_html/web/css**
 or 
**/home/test/var/www/test.com/public_html/web/js**
return error 403

**I try get static file use the url like this test.com/css/style.css**

Comment: Has nginx access to `/home/test/var/www/test.com/public_html/web` and all its subdirs?

Comment: Permission to dir /home/test = 750, 
but i have few web sites on Joomla on thise server  and there nginx good work

Comment: what are the permissions for /home/test/var/www/test.com/public_html/web? `ls -all /home/test/var/www/test.com/public_html/web`

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem. 
I forgot add user www-data ( the nginx process ) to group test ( the test is owner all files in your home dir ).